# Contraction mapping in $C$ or $C^{0}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for a contraction mapping $A\rightarrow R, A\in R $ and complete, such that it is not differentiable everywhere in $A$. In the extreme case is there such a (contraction) function which is nowhere differentiable ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) $f(x) = \frac{|x|}{2}$ is a contraction mapping that is not differentiable everywhere (if $A$ doesn't contain a neighboorhood of $0$, just translate it)

2) every Lipschitz function is almost everywhere differentiable, this result is usually known as the [Rademacher's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem)